# Is there a way to customize the size of the UITableViewCell's backgroundView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I'm trying to assign a custom backgroundView to a UITableViewCell. The table is Grouped.

I'm a bit of a trailblazer so instead of using the typical width of a background view, 302 pixels, I'm trying to use a 300 px wide image.

Here's my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // a 300 pixel wide image
    UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tableViewCellBackgroundTop"];
    UIImageView *theBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:backgroundImage];
    theBackgroundView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 49);
    cell.backgroundView = theBackgroundView;
}
```

If I run this in the simulator and measure with xScope, the cell still appears to be 302 pixels wide. What gives? Is there some other property I need to set to make the framework respect the frame I've assigned to the background view, or were table view cells not intended to be customized in this fashion?

Comment: I'm sorry. I think I'm getting tired.

Comment: Don't `UITableViewCell`s just inherit the width of the `UITableView`?

Comment: I believe so, but it's the backgroundView's width that I'm concerned with. Also I don't want to change the width of the Table View because that has its own background view.

Comment: heres one thing to try: `theBackgroundView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;`

Comment: Tom - that actually appears to work for code similar above, but what if the Image View I'm using is a stretchable image?

Comment: Try my solution here http://stackoverflow.com/a/16618362/344895

Answer (score 3):

You can create a `UIView` instance and make `theBackgroundView` a subview of it, and then set `cell.backgroundView` to the created view:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 49)];
[view addSubview:theBackgroundView];
cell.backgroundView = view;
```