# How to change the size of a UITableView background image?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

How would i go about changing the size of a uitableview background image? By default it automatically sizes the image for me but i want mine a little smaller. I've tried doing the following...

```
let image = UIImage(named: "noFoldersImage")
        let iv = UIImageView(image: image)
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        iv.layer.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.midX, y: self.view.frame.midY, width: 200, height: 200)
        self.tableView.backgroundView = iv
```

But it doesn't seem to work, any ideas? Thanks

Comment: You can set background to clear color tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear. And add imageview below the tableView, You can custom this imageView as You want

Comment: @Luke Smith DO THIS -:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11958081/is-there-a-way-to-customize-the-size-of-the-uitableviewcells-backgroundview

Answer (score 5):

You may change the implement like this:

```
    let image = UIImage(named: "noFoldersImage")
    let iv = UIImageView(image: image)
    iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    iv.layer.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.midX, y: self.view.frame.midY, width: 200, height: 200)
    let tableViewBackgroundView = UIView()
    tableViewBackgroundView.addSubview(iv)
    self.tableView.backgroundView = tableViewBackgroundView
```